# How do I get Monopoly gold?

Tags: monopoly-hotels

I am playing Monopoly Hotels, and like all free-to-play iOS real-time games (think Farmville, etc), you have a regular currency (Monopoly dollars) and a premium currency (Monopoly gold). I know I can get gold by paying real-world money, but I would like to avoid that.

The game gives you some gold to start with, and then you periodically earn more. I thought it was through levelling up, but my last level-up didn't get me any gold.

What is the in-game free way to earn gold?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the gold image then click free gold. It should give you 2 videos, just watch them and you'll get free gold. But save them wisely for the fancy restaurant.

Comment: Is there any other ways? I have those two gold, which brings me to a total of 7, and the Fancy Restaurant requires 80. I haven't been able to watch the videos more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You can complete stickers, and some give you gold - but I don't remember which ones do.

Answer (score 1):

You keep waiting and once you have built in 5 hotels or so your daily GO bonus gives you 2-4 gold a day instead of the regular currency.

Answer (score 1):

In the left corner, where you click on the free gold, is a red hurricane-like thing. Clicking on that and creating a free account provides you with 3 free gold coins.

Comment: That would be the Origin account sign up. :)